# pip install error with proxy on installing second package

Tags: proxy, pip

I have met some error when running
 `pip install google-api-python-client --proxy http://10.10.40.10:80` ,
 as follow details.
`Downloading/unpacking google-api-python-client
  Downloading google_api_python_client-1.6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB): 53kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev (from google-api-python-client)
  Real name of requirement oauth2client is oauth2client`

however, it's no problem when installing 'future' package which don't deploy packages ( like enum,  futures, six, rsa.,),

Comment: resolved by upgrade pip to latest. ** pip install --upgrade pip**

Answer (score 0):

need to update pip with resolved: 
**pip install google-api-python-client  --proxy http://10.10.40.10:80**
'Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client in 
./lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.6.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2dev,>=1.6.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (4.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.9.2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (0.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client) (0.4.2)
'